# How to download and install JDK using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a script which will check the java version in client's computer and update the JDK by downloading the latest one from Oracles website. Please help with the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to download files from a website using just batch. Pure batch has no web functionality. If the file is available on an FTP server, you could use the built-in FTP tool to download it but only if the server supports FTP active mode. Otherwise, you will have to use a different script language. Here is an example for a PowerShell script which downloads a file via FTP or HTTP:

```
function downloadFile($url, $targetFile)
{
    "Downloading $url"
    $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
    $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $request.set_Timeout(15000) #15 second timeout
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)
    $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create
    $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
    $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
    $downloadedBytes = $count
    while ($count -gt 0)
    {
        [System.Console]::CursorLeft = 0
        [System.Console]::Write("Downloaded {0}K of {1}K", [System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024), $totalLength)
        $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
        $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
        $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
    }
    "`nFinished Download"
    $targetStream.Flush()
    $targetStream.Close()
    $targetStream.Dispose()
    $responseStream.Dispose()
}

downloadFile "<url to the file to download>" "<local path where to save the file>"
```

You can save this code in a `.ps1` file and call it from your batch code.

You could also use a tool like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html). It also allows you to download files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest  https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=236886_42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60 -OutFile jdk8.exe"

jdk8.exe /s
```